# On the cycles of 1D (general) and 2D (specific) cellular automata (CA), on the use of GraphPlot and on a specific 2D 4-neighbor square CA

Tags: graphics, cellular-automata

My question has two parts. The first concerns a general feature in 1D cellular automata and the 2nd a specific 2D model.

1st question: In the documentation we can find the command

`GraphPlot[# -> CellularAutomaton[54, #] & /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, n]]`

with which we can visualize the cyclic behaviour of any 1D cellular automaton with any given n.
For example, for rule 54 and n=5, we find no cycles (meaning no configurations that repeat after a given number of timesteps), but only one (the trivial) fixed point (a configuration that remains unchanged under the evolution of the cellular automaton).
For rule 54 and n = 10, however, I have a much more complicated behaviour.

How can I have the information of these graphs into a list and avoid counting by hand from the graphs? Note that I don't want to follow what is usually suggested for cycles in other posts. I don't want to recalculate something like

`NestWhileList[CellularAutomaton[54, #] &, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, UnsameQ, All]`

since in order to get all the different periods or fixed points I would still need to do some postprocessing of the vectors and the periods, while with the GraphPlot you get a free meal!

Say, I have 2 distinct periods of 30, 15 distinct periods of 4 and 1 fixed point of 1. I want something like that:
$\{30(2), 4(15), 1(1)\}$. On top of that, I want, if possible, to be able to get 1 state from each cycle with some command in a vector form, say `{1, 0, 0, 0, 1}`.

2nd question: Classify the following 2D cellular automaton and find its cycles the same way as for  the previous case

I have the following 2D square 4-neighbor cellular automaton (I hope I didn't mix or incorrectly used any of these terms).
By $i$-index I denote x-direction (horizontal) and $j$ the y-direction (vertical). I want my cellular automaton to have the rule:

$$ s_{ij}^{t+1} = F(s_{ij}^t, s_{i+1, j}^t, s_{i, j+1}^t, s_{i+1, j+1}^t) = s_{ij}^t + s_{i+1, j}^t + s_{i, j+1}^t + s_{i+1, j+1}^t \;\;\;\;\; mod(2) $$

I assume periodic boundary conditions in both dimensions.

Does this rule have any specific name? Is it known/used anywhere? Can I somehow do a GraphPlot and find its cycles and behaviour similarly as before?

For all rules in the database we can do, for example,

`RulePlot[CellularAutomaton[{25552, 3}]]`

and we can plot the RulePlot of the model. How can I do the same for my 2D model? I want for each case two $2\times2$ lattices, one as the input and the other as the output.